# PHP: Wrapping all matching characters in html

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

I want to wrap all slashes "/", and parenthesis "(" and ")" in the same html. Is there a less repetitive way to do this with PHP? A regex perhaps? Right now I'm using the following code:

```
    $para = str_replace('/','<span class="lite">/</span>',$para);
    $para = str_replace('(','<span class="lite">(</span>',$para);
    $para = str_replace('(','<span class="lite">)</span>',$para);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This code workz; why use other?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$para = preg_replace('!([/\(\)])!','<span class="lite">$1</span>',$para);
```

But I'm not sure that a regular expression search-and-replace is more efficient than three simple text search-and-replace actions.